# Plotting 2 columns with day-interval-PNG's using split, cut and for loop in R

Tags: r, plot

I have the following dataframe:

```
myDates <- seq(as.Date("2013/1/1"), as.Date("2013/1/10"), "days");        
x1 <- 1:10
y1 <- 11:20
myTable <- data.frame(myDates, x1, y1)
```

Now I aim to divide the dates into 2-day intervals, and then plot `x1` versus `y1` into `png` files, *with a loop* perhaps, so that I end up with `5 png files`.

My idea was *to divide* the `data.frame` into 2 day intervals, with `split` and `cut` function, and then use a `for-loop` to go plotting into the different levels one by one as follows:

```
twoDayInt <- seq(as.Date("2013/01/01"), as.Date("2013/01/10"), by = "2 days")
myTableSplit <- split(myTable, cut(myTable$myDates, twoDayInt))
for (j in 1:length(twoDayInt)) {
    fileName <- sprintf("/home/kigode/Desktop/%s_2dayInteval_%02i.png ", "myGraph",j) 
    png(fileName,width=700,height=650)
    # this is where i cant figure out what to put
    plot(myTableSplit$x1[j], myTableSplit$y1[j])
}
dev.off()
```

Now i'm stuck at the for loop section and would ask for a clue on how to proceed.

Comment: Your `dev.off()` should be inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few small mistakes here:

- First, as juba pointed out `dev.off()` should go inside the loop.
- Second, `myTableSplit` is a list of `data.frames`. So, the elements should be accessed using `j` as `myTableSplit[[j]]`.
- Third, the `x1` and `y1` columns should be indexed without the `j`.
- Fourth, your counter variable `twoDayInt` has one less entry (5 instead of 6). This results in `myTableSplit` in `cut` not resulting in all 5 parts, but only 4. Therefore, as a fix, I've extended the range of `twoDayInt` to until `2013/01/12` and then indexed only the first 5 values in the `for-loop` (although this could be done in an entirely different manner, I supposed you'd rather want a fix for your code).

Correcting for all these errors:

```
myDates <- seq(as.Date("2013/1/1"), as.Date("2013/1/10"), "days")
x1 <- 1:10
y1 <- 11:20

myTable <- data.frame(myDates, x1, y1)
# note the end date change here
twoDayInt <- seq(as.Date("2013/01/01"), as.Date("2013/01/12"), by = "2 days")
myTableSplit <- split(myTable, cut(myTable$myDates, twoDayInt))
# index 1:5, not the 6th value of twoDayInt
# you could change this to seq_along(myTableSplit)
for (j in head(seq_along(twoDayInt), -1)) {
    fileName <- sprintf("/home/kigode/Desktop/%s_2dayInteval_%02i.png", "myGraph",j) 
    png(fileName,width=700,height=650);
    # [[.]] indexing for accessing list and $x1 etc.. for the column of data.frame
    plot(myTableSplit[[j]]$x1, myTableSplit[[j]]$y1)
    dev.off() # inside the loop
}
```

**Edit:** As an alternative, what you intend to do could be directly achieved by using `lapply` and picking up the rows of your `data.frame` two at a time:

```
# here, the number 1,3,5,7,9 are given to idx 1-by-1
lapply(seq(1, nrow(myTable), by=2), function(idx) {
    fileName <- sprintf("/home/kigode/Desktop/%s_2dayInteval_%02i.png", "myGraph",idx) 
    png(fileName,width=700,height=650);
    plot(myTable$x1[idx:(idx+1)], myTable$y1[idx:(idx+1)])
    dev.off()
})
```

Comment: thanks for the corrections. Both codes work like a charm! I'm trying to see how lapply works though :)

Comment: It is a good time to start looking at examples from `?lapply`.